# Equating string variables in Perl?

Tags: perl

I created a Perl script to extract file name out of a relative path.
Here is a sub which takes the path as an argument then calculates the name from it then appends it to a global variable.

```
my $all_names = "";
sub check_line
{
    my @args = @_;
    my $line = $args[0]; #take the path
    my @paths = split(/\\|\//, $line); #split according to folder
    my $last = @paths;
    $last = $last - 1;
    my $name = $paths[$last]; #take the file name
    chomp($name); #remove \n character from end of string
    my ($ext) = $name =~ /(\..+)/; #extract the file extension from file name
    if(($ext eq ".h") || ($ext eq ".cpp") || ($ext eq ".c")) #filter the required files
    {
         $all_names = $all_names . "$name "; #append the file names to global variable
    }
}
```

Now this script is working fine in Perl 5.005 (Yes we have that old version of Perl too!).
But if I run it on Perl 5.10 it wont run properly.
The check for file extension always returns false.
Even when I print the file extension I am getting it properly as `.h` or `.c` but even if I compare it individually

```
if($ext eq ".c")
```

Then it is returning false.
What might be wrong over here?
Thank You.

Comment: If you print `length($ext)`, does it print 2 for `.c` ?

Comment: @Andomar no, its printing 3. Why is this happening?
Shouldnt chomp remove all those \n. \r characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not because of a change in version.

You probably have a file with CR LF endings, and you're running on a non-Windows machine.

You can fix the line endings with `dos2unix` or similar.

Alternatively, you could change

```
chomp($name);
```

to

```
$name =~ s/\r?\n\z//;
```

or better yet

```
$name =~ s/\s+\z//;
```

Comment: The problem is with cygwin on windows 7.
With old version of Perl the script is working even on Sun without dos2unix.

Comment: doesnt chomp remove \r characters?

Comment: can you please explain what \z is & \s is?

Comment: @Cool_Coder, No, it removes the contents of `$/`, which is a LF by default.

Comment: `\s` matches a whitespace character. `\z` matches the end of the string. (Many people incorrectly use `$` when they mean `\z`.)

Comment: Thank You! It is working fine now :)
Just wanted to know why chomp is not doing this already?

Comment: @Cool_Coder, cause `chomp` was designed to remove line endings, and only line endings. True, it's more useful to delete all trailing whitespace, but I guess it didn't occur to the author.